# How to return a anonymous NamedTuple in python defined only in the return type hint

Tags: python, typescript, type-hinting

I come from Typescript, new to Python. When I have 2 things to return from a function and I only use these 2 keys for that function return type and nowhere else in the code, I don't create a complete class but I instead use typescript convinient syntax:

```
fn(): {
    'return_key_1': number,
    'return_key_2': string,
} {
    // statements..
    return { 
    {
        'return_key_1': 5,
        'return_key_2': 'hello',
        'error_key': 9, // IDE shows an error here as I didn't declared this key
    }
}
```

which enables to create rapidly return data structure without the boilerplate of declaring a entire class, and I have all the IDE autocomplete and errors/warning associated to that data-structure.

Is there the same in Python ? I saw there are NamedTuple, or new @dataclass classes from Python 3.7, but how do you make Python return a NamedTuple with defined keys without declaring the class elsewhere but in the return type ?

I tried:

```
def fn(self) -> NamedTuple('MyTuple', fields = [('params', str), ('cursor_end', int)]):
    return {
        'params': 'hello',
        'cursor_end': 4,
    }
```

But PyCharm says "Expected type 'MyTuple', got 'dict[str, str | int]' instead"

Comment: I'm not familiar with typescript. But why do you need to have the keys defined? Or in other words, what would be the problem with returning a dictionary and just writing it so that the keys are always the correct ones?

Comment: @Bill Returning only a dictionary doesn't let the IDE know what keys that function should expect and their respective associated type, so I don't have autocompletion and errors/warning in case I add/miss some keys :/

Comment: There is no way to do this anonymously as far as I am aware if you are sticking to the  actual python type annotation spec. Of course, IDEs can do whatever they want.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well yes basically I just want to get back to the confort I had in strongly typed languages with autocompletion and warning

Comment: @JeremLachkar then you should use a tool like `mypy` or `pyright` on strict settings. PyCharm is mostly on the level of a souped-up linter. But I admit, that is mostly just my impression.

Comment: Also, you mean statically typed, not strongly typed. Python is generally considered a strongly typed langauge. It added optional static typing, with support from third-party tools (although `mypy` might as well be official since Guido works on it)

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what problem you’re wanting to solve with this.

Comment: Are you trying to return a tuple with certain named fields (indexable, hashable) or a dict with certain key/val structure (mutable, _O(1)_ membership test)? Is your goal just to make PyCharm show some helpful hints, or do you actually want to run through type checkers? It's not very clear, please edit the question and title.

Comment: From what I understand, a dict is like a C++ map (unknown keys name, same type for all keys). I wanted to return a data structure like a class, but without declaring explicitly since I use it only for the return type of one function :)

Comment: @JeremLachkar yeah, see, Python have very limited support for that. You have to understand, Python is a nominally typed system. it has very limited (and clunky) support for structural typing, but you aren't going to get anything like TypeScript, where you just expect things like anonymous structural types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your sample function returns a dict, you should type the returning value with [`typing.TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) instead:

```
from typing import TypedDict

def f() -> TypedDict('', {
    'return_key_1': int,
    'return_key_2': str,
}):
    return {
        'return_key_1': 5,
        'return_key_2': 'hello',
        'error_key': 9, # PyCharm shows an error here
    }
```

Note, as @juanpa.arrivillaga points out in the comment, that while the above looks clean and conveniently works in PyCharm, it is unfortunately not officially part of the Python type annotation system. You would have to define the `TypedDict` in advance instead of inline in order to conform to the official specifications and satisfy tools that strictly adhere to the specs, like the example below, which is almost identical to the code above except in naming the `TypedDict` in advance:

```
from typing import TypedDict

MyDict = TypedDict('MyDict', {
    'return_key_1': int,
    'return_key_2': str,
})

def f() -> MyDict:
    return {
        'return_key_1': 'a',
        'return_key_2': 'hello',
        'error_key': 9,
    }
```

Demo in mypy: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=4fbb933f9f9441fced1931d7b32d4c7d

Comment: @blhsing yeah, I mean, PyCharm can do that. But it isn't a valid type annotation according to the Python type system. But it works in PyCharm, but people should really understand, this is rejected as a valid annotation by `mypy` and `pyright`, two very popular static analysis tools